# I want to deploy my rails app with Mysql as database. I want to go with free heroku server. what are the limitations of this free server?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

i have a small `rails` Application with `Mysql` database.i want to deploy this application to `heroku`. but i am not getting the `limitations` of it. like what is the `maximum database size` and `maximum application size`. i know only the `ram` limitation is upto `512 mb`. how many `instances` it will provides and what is the `bandwidth` of it etc,like this i want to know all limitations of this `free hosting` on `heroku`.

Comment: as per my knowledge, you have to use postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans) it breaks the heroku plans down for you.

The free plan which is Hobby Tier for example

1. has an enforced row limits of `10,000` rows in your database for hobby-dev
2. No in-memory cache
3. No fork/follow support: Fork and follow, used to create replica
   databases and master-slave setups, are not supported
4. Expected uptime of 99.5% each month.